# Javascript select menu onchange when it loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, firefox, selected

I'm using a select menu:

```
<select id="form_frame1" name="frame1" onchange="getChart(this);">
  <option value="area_chart_google" >Area Chart</option>
  <option value="area_chart_2" selected="selected">Stacked Chart</option>
</select>
```

getChart suposed to be fired ONLY when changing the selection:

```
function getChart(selection) {
    alert(selection.value);
    //do something
}
```

The problem is that once I load the page I get: **area_chart_google**: That's not even the choice previously selected! so there are two things I don't understand:

1. Why is onChange event fired once I load the page (onload)?
2. Why it chooses the first option, even though is not previously selected?

I just found this function, I guess this is the problem:

```
jQuery(function() {
 if (localStorage.getItem('form_frame1')) {
    jQuery("#form_frame1 option").eq(localStorage.getItem('form_frame1')).prop('selected', true);
    jQuery("#form_frame1 option").change();
 }

 jQuery("#form_frame1").on('change', function() {
    localStorage.setItem('form_frame1', jQuery('option:selected', this).index());
 }); 
});
```

Comment: I don't see any jQuery in your code. Also, do you have other JavaScript in your page you're not showing here?

Comment: It would not fire unless you triggered it somehow..

Comment: You were right, I found a Jquery that was causing the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually using jquery then why not try

```
$('#form_frame1').change(function(){
   getChart($('#form_frame1').val());
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

when you refresh the page it will automatically selects first option.

Comment: But it's also happening when I first load the page. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/6H9dr/1/

Use like below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#form_frame1').change(function() {
    alert('Hi');
});
```

});